# Cassandra astyanax sql query errors out when where clause is used

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

select with where clause works fine in cassandra cqlsh> but not from Astyanax. However, SLQ clause without where clause works fine from astyanax. Not sure what I'm missing any thoughts?

```
CREATE TABLE personalization1 (
                       username text primary key,
                      incidentPage text,
                      timelinePage text,
                      );

insert into personalization1 (username,incidentpage,timelinepage) values ('3cd70b90-d211-11e3-8774-14109fdb7013','3cd70b90-d211-11e3-8774-14109fdb7013','3cd70b90-d211-11e3-8774-14109fdb7013');

SELECT * FROM personalization1 where username='3cd70b90-d211-11e3-8774-14109fdb7013' ;
```

com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: [host=10.65.240.89(10.65.240.89):9160, latency=237(342), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with "equals" operator)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:159)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:65)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:28)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:151)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:119)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:338)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery.execute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:41)
    at com.ebay.timeline.dao.PersonaliztionDAOTest.test(PersonaliztionDAOTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with "equals" operator)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:36625)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_cql_query(Cassandra.java:1525)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql_query(Cassandra.java:1511)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftCqlQuery.execute_cql_query(ThriftCqlQuery.java:33)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery$1.internalExecute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:46)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery$1.internalExecute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:43)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice from the stack trace that the "execute_cql_query" function is being used, not "execute_cql3_query", so the query being run is being run like it was executed in `cqlsh -2`, that is most likely the issue.  The name of the primary key from cql2's view of things is probably "key".

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue